# How to create a waiting ellipsis in a Perl program?

Tags: perl

The following code is not working as it seems it should be:

```
print "Processing your listing";
sleep($n);
print ".";
sleep($n);
print ".";
sleep($n);
print ".\n\n";
```

Trying to get something where there is a `.`, then another `.`, then another `.`, and then `Process complete!`

Answer (score 2):

By default Perl buffers your output. To get stuff like this to work you need to disable it.

Use

```
$| = 1
```

or, rather better

```
STDOUT->autoflush
```

at the start of your program.

Comment: How do I used this? Where? I don't follow. I mean, where do I put your `$| = 1`?

Comment: As I said, at the start of your program. Specifically, before any output that must be flushed immediately it is printed.

Comment: What exactly does this do? I want to have a personalized console message.

Comment: Is there a way I can do this in the spirit of my OP?

Comment: The first enables autoflush on the current output channel; the second explicity enables autoflush on `STDOUT`, which is normally the current output.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Just put one or other of those before the code you already have.

Comment: I presume you realise that you need to set `$n` to something non-zero?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. What I have up there returns a pause _before_ "Processing listing", so that's not right...

Comment: And have you added one of my additional lines before that first `print` statement?

Comment: Doing that now... OK, do you mean like [this](http://pastebin.com/fVrw05KN)? I suspect this is not what you were asking because it doesn't work.

Comment: Your code gives this on my machine: `Can't locate object method "autoflush" via package "IO::File" at program line 1286, <STDIN> line 2.`

Comment: okay then you have an older version of Perl. Use `$| = 1` instead of the `autoflush` line. Like [this](http://pastebin.com/M6WZ4RPW)

Comment: Perfect, now, I'm curious. What is happening here with your symbols? I mean, what is `$|` anyway? The `1` is a second, right?

Comment: It's the `$OUTPUT_AUTOFLUSH` variable, [documented here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles). Yes, `$n = 1` is one second.

Answer (score 2):

I'm actually going to suggest against doing this manually. There are fantastic CPAN modules which provide the feature you actually want, a progress bar. For example there are:

- [ProgressBar::Stack](https://metacpan.org/pod/ProgressBar%3a%3aStack)
- [Text::ProgressBar::Bar](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text%3a%3aProgressBar%3a%3aBar)
- [Term::ProgressBar](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term%3a%3aProgressBar)

Here's the example from ProgressBar::Stack:

```
    use ProgressBar::Stack;

    init_progress;
    sleep(1);
    update_progress 20;
    sleep(2);
    update_progress 60;
    sleep(2);
    update_progress 100;
    print "\n";

    init_progress(message => "Calculating");
    my $sum = 0;
    for_progress {
        $sum+=$_;
        sleep(1);
    } 0..10;
    print "\nSum = $sum\n";
```