# Behavior of Perl sleep() I don't understand

Tags: perl

I was trying to implement a 'count down' where from 5 to 1 the number would be printed and then wait for 1 second. However, using the code below, the terminal displays nothing for 5 seconds and prints `5.. 4.. 3.. 2.. 1..`. Uuh, what?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.16;

# Test stuff, or so help me!
for (reverse 1..5) {
    print "$_.. ";
    sleep 1;
}

say '';
```

Comment: Have you tried flushing the output? Perhaps add something like: `BEGIN { select (STDERR); $| = 1; select (STDOUT); $| = 1; }`

Comment: [Similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21948849/how-to-create-a-waiting-ellipsis-in-a-perl-program).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

print to a terminal is usually line-buffered. You have to flush stdout.

```
print "$_.. ";
flush STDOUT;
sleep 1;
```

Comment: Note that `flush` is not a builtin function, but a method of `IO::Handle` – on older perls this requires a `use IO::Handle` to activate. As it's a method call, it should be written `STDOUT->flush` instead. Otherwise, +1 for an elegant solution

Answer (score 2):

Or you may use the perl special variable **$|** and set it to a non-zero value and Perl will flush automatically after every write.

```
$|++;
# Or like this
$| = 1;

for (reverse 1..5) {
    print "$_.. ";
    sleep 1;
}
```